# XML Nodes - Searching 1 Node Getting its child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

i tried to do learn something more about xml.
In my application i have 1 button, 1 textbox for searching a head nodes and another one to get the child nodes of this head node.

Example:

```
<root>
 <werk>
  <titel>So What?</titel>
  <gattung>Pop</gattung>
  <interpret>Pink</interpret>
  <komponist>Max Martin</komponist>
  <entstehungsjahr>2008</entstehungsjahr>
 </werk>
</root>
```

Now if i am searching in my first textbox after the title -> `So What?`, how can i get the child nodes of `So what?` ?

The Child nodes would be:

```
Pop
Pink
Max Martin
2008
```

Thx for trying to help me.

Comment: Those aren't *child* nodes - they're *sibling* nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a bit confused about XML. The element-node `titel` has exactly one child node, a text-node with the value of "So What?". The element nodes of `gattung` etc. are siblings of `titel`, not children!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)
or if you're feeling frisky [XML Serialization](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization)
It is NOT recommended that you attempt to do this with string splits & regex etc.

edit: using the above technologies should mitigate nay grammatical issues such as child versus sibling.

edit: adding a code example using linq to xml

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<root>
 <werk>
  <titel>So What?</titel>
  <gattung>Pop</gattung>
  <interpret>Pink</interpret>
  <komponist>Max Martin</komponist>
  <entstehungsjahr>2008</entstehungsjahr>
 </werk>
</root>");
            var elementsAfterTitel = doc.Element("root").Element("werk").Element("titel").ElementsAfterSelf();
            foreach (var element in elementsAfterTitel)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh well thx for telling me this.
But it is possible to search after SO What? And get the following strings?

Pop
Pink
Max Martin
2008

Comment: if you use linq to xml, you can search for sibling elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a little confusion here about the definition of "child node". In the given example, `<titel>`, `<gattung>`, `<interpret>`, `<komponist>` and `<entstehungsjahr>` are child nodes of `<werk>`. From what I have gathered, given the title you want to get the values that the other tags contain. Here's one way you can do that:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"path\to\file.xml");

List<string> values = new List<string>(); // Create a new list

// Select the 'werk' node whose title is 'So what?'
XmlNode werk = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/werk[titel='So what?']");
// If you're getting the title from a textbox, then obviously you won't hardcode 
// 'So what?' here.

// Add the value of each child node to the list
foreach (XmlNode node in werk.ChildNodes)
{
    values.Add(node.InnerText);
}
```

Then simply output the contents of the list where you want to display them (in the other textbox I reckon).